# unabel to connect to ms server 2017

Tags: android, sql-server

When ever I click on the login button it always shows me check ur internet toast I don't know why I have also turned off my firewall also please help
I have also passed the internet permission also in the manifest .
Can someone also share the link from where I can learn how to pass values in android from sql server
thanks in advance !

## MainActivity.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
        // Declaring layout button, edit texts
        Button login;
        EditText username,password;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        // End Declaring layout button, edit texts

        // Declaring connection variables
        Connection con;
        String un,pass,db,ip;
        //End Declaring connection variables

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Getting values from button, texts and progress bar
            login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            // End Getting values from button, texts and progress bar

            // Declaring Server ip, username, database name and password
            ip = "LAPTOP-KOS272HK";
            db = "fmv";
            un = "username";
            pass = "password";
            // Declaring Server ip, username, database name and password

            // Setting up the function when button login is clicked
            login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    CheckLogin checkLogin = new CheckLogin();// this is the Asynctask, which is used to process in background to reduce load on app process
                    checkLogin.execute("");
                }
            });
            //End Setting up the function when button login is clicked
        }

        public class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
        {
            String z = "";
            Boolean isSuccess = false;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute()
            {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String r)
            {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(isSuccess)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , "Login Successfull" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //finish();
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params)
            {
                String usernam = username.getText().toString();
                String passwordd = password.getText().toString();
                if(usernam.trim().equals("")|| passwordd.trim().equals(""))
                    z = "Please enter Username and Password";
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        con = connectionclass(un, pass, db, ip);        // Connect to database
                        if (con == null)
                        {
                            z = "Check Your Internet Access!";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Change below query according to your own database.
                            String query = "select * from login where user_name= '" + usernam.toString() + "' and pass_word = '"+ passwordd.toString() +"'  ";
                            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                            if(rs.next())
                            {
                                z = "Login successful";
                                isSuccess=true;
                                con.close();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                z = "Invalid Credentials!";
                                isSuccess = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        isSuccess = false;
                        z = ex.getMessage();
                    }
                }
                return z;
            }
        }


        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public Connection connectionclass(String user, String password, String database, String server)
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            Connection connection = null;
            String ConnectionURL = null;
            try
            {
                Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
                ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server + database + ";user=" + user+ ";password=" + password + ";";
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
            }
            catch (SQLException se)
            {
                Log.e("error here 1 : ", se.getMessage());
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                Log.e("error here 2 : ", e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("error here 3 : ", e.getMessage());
            }
            return connection;
        }
    }
```

## Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tanis.logi">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: `ip = "LAPTOP-KOS272HK";` does not look like an Ip address. Yes you need to use url or IP address of your server, not what you use here

Comment: can you help me how to find that in ms server

Comment: that should be IP address of your server. Do you know what is IP address?